# Why does my image not load on full size?

Tags: html, image, html-table, html4

I need to make a table-based layout and made my table width 550px. And then I loaded an image with original width of 550px but on browser I only have 449px. I want to make in on full width. And also I have extra space between cells.

```
<table style="width:550px;margin:0 auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                <td style="font-size:12px; line-height: 12px; width: 100%; text-align: right; color:#5A99B1;">Click <b>here</b> for the online version</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100%; height:10px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <img style="width: 100%;" src="border-top.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:50%; background-color:white;">
                    <img src="brugadalogo.png" />
                </td>
                <td style="width:50%; background-color:white; text-align: right;">
                    <img src="msdlogo.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: "I nees to make a table based layout" - Do you really? Please don't. It'll make your life easier, you'll be richer, wealthier, more attracive and your eternal sould won't feel as tarnished. Just saying.

Comment: I understand what your saying :P But i don't have the time to argue about it - that were my specifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table columns are not uniformly even. You have 3 rows, the first 2 have 1 column and the last one has 2 columns. Even if you have the right percentages, it is better to have it distributed evenly. Such as have all 3 rows have or "take the space of" 2 columns.

What I mean by that is that instead of using widths, you should use `colspan`. Also remove the width from the image, if you want its original size, it should get it by default.

```
<table style="width:550px;margin:0 auto;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                <td **colspan="2"** style="font-size:12px; line-height: 12px; text-align: right; color:#5A99B1;">Click <b>here</b> for the online version</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td **colspan="2"** style="height:10px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <img src="border-top.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:white;">
                    <img src="brugadalogo.png" />
                </td>
                <td style="background-color:white; text-align: right;">
                    <img src="msdlogo.png" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: It helped and it answered my question. But there is one more that i didn't mentioned: my border-top.png has 10px height but the td has 20px. No padding, no margin, nothing i can figure it out, even if i put 10px height to my td - as you can see in my example. Any ideeas why?

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. Try inspecting the TD, TR and IMG using Firebug's Layout tab, that should give you the exact dimentions of everything like padding, margin, border. Maybe there is a style being inherited somewhere. Also you could try setting the height to the TR instead of the TD.

Comment: That was the weirdest thing. Firebug's layout said 10px height for image no padding,border,outline,margin, nothing and 20px for td, that has 10px height forced but nothing. I found a solution and set line-height:1px for td and it worked even if there wasn't a clear explanation.